# Unexplained Atlas Mongodb Collection Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I had originally applied the "ValidationLevel: strict" to my mongodb database collections and later modified the schema "ValidationLevel" to "moderate" but I noticed that the default "strict" is reapplied and leads to document validation failure. I have even dropped the database and recreate it, when this is done the "moderate" validationlevel is initially applied but is soon reverted to "strict".

Perhaps there's a cache somewhere on Atlas that is causing this to happen. Note I am using the free Atlas version.

Any pointers would be helpful.

## Update:

This is the error I get when I git the collection during test from my IDE (Pycharm Professional Edition)

```
[2023-04-16 09:29:13 AM WAT] ERROR loggable: __init__.py - setup_env - 198 - [Validation Set up error: users invalid: {'ns': '5ca333b3cf09a23a5563c82b_flaskdb-test.users', 'nInvalidDocuments': 0, 'nNonCompliantDocuments': 2, 'nrecords': 2, 'nIndexes': 0, 'keysPerIndex': {}, 'indexDetails': {}, 'valid': False, 'repaired': False, 'warnings': [], 'errors': ["Detected one or more documents not compliant with the collection's schema. Check logs for log id 5363500."], 'extraIndexEntries': [], 'missingIndexEntries': [], 'corruptRecords': [], 'advice': 'A corrupt namespace has been detected.
```

Comment: If you [View Existing Validation Rules](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/view-existing-validation-rules/), what does it show?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it shows the modified index, that's how I know

Comment: Are you using some ORM or IDE, etc., that is rewriting the index?

Comment: I am using NoSQLBooster for Mongodb IDE, the free version

Comment: I've never used NoSQLBooster and I've never experienced mystery collection modifications.  I doubt Atlas is changing any collections on its own so I'd look closely at NoSQLBooster.

Comment: @rickhg12hs just tested it on MongoDB Compass and the same thing is happening ... So it's not from NoSQLBooster IDE. Funny thing it's only happening on one database "flaskdb-test", every other have their applied validation schema intact

Comment: There must be some process that is accessing the server and modifying the collection.  Try to isolate exactly when it happens with an independent observing process.  Is it correlated to when you start a program/IDE/etc.?  Does anyone else have access to this collection?  Perhaps a member of your team is modifying the collection.